# Setting order object in session_quote

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, session

I'm trying to set an `$order` object to the `session_quote`. However, when I get the `$order` object after setting it, the data and other information are null yet the object remains. How can I set the order object to the `session_quote` correctly so that the data is still within the order object?

Example:

```
$order= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->setOrder($order);
```

Getting order from session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
$sessionOrder = $session->getOrder();
```

Results in order object with no data or payment information.

```
$orderId = $sessionOrder->getId(); /* is null */
$orderData = $sessionOrder->getData(); /* is null */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote` ->getOrder() is not a magic method, but a real method exists in the class:

```
/**
 * Retrieve order model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    if (is_null($this->_order)) {
        $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        if ($this->getOrderId()) {
            $this->_order->load($this->getOrderId());
        }
    }
    return $this->_order;
}
```

From the logic above, is is apparent why you are getting a null'd order Object.

What you need to do is simply store the OrderId into the session object.
When you call for getOrder(), it will then populate the order correctly in the result. See code in getOrder() method.

Thus use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->setOrderId($orderId);
```

When things don't work as expected, go have a look at the class that you are using.

Not all methods are magic methods in magento, sometimes a method can be a magic method in once class, and not in another. (one of the features that can make magento code both confusing, and powerful to extend)

Comment: Great thorough answer! I have a better understanding by looking in  `[webroot]/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Session/Quote.php` as you suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$sessionOrder = $session->getData('order');
```

EDIT:
That would work, but it's bad coding in this context as explained in the comment. It will also make the code difficult to maintain as it'll be difficult to trace how and where the order is set.

Comment: This bypasses the built in class functionality, and is not the right thing to do.

Comment: getData **is** a built-in method. What's wrong with it? Please enlighten.

Comment: I am not disputing that getData is a built in method, but in this class/functionality context, it use is not appropriate. As already explained in the answer, the class has a method to retrieve the order object, and cache it internally in the class. Thus using setOrder() stores the order object in the Objects Data array, and it is not required to go whack a whole object into the class. You would be retrieving an object from the Data array that is potentially out of sync to what is stored in the database. The built in getorder method prevents that.

Comment: To continue: Using getData() to bypass a class built in  methods are, at times approriate. In this instance, and considering the OP use requirements, it is not, thus making your answer not valid.

Comment: A valid point on out-of-synch data with the database. If that is the concern, then it is indeed bad to use _getData_ and _setOrderId_ is the way to go.

Comment: @ProxiBlue agree with your advice on the method to use, it however is no guarantee against the out of sync issue you mentioned. Imagine 1.) getOrder (will be cached in variable _order) 2.) external api call to update order 3.) another call to getOrder, will return _order which is out of sync to database

Comment: @Fooman - valid point.